# Add line feed between attributes in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linefeed

I have tried to put line break between my **specific** XML attribute, but with no success so far.

Basically, I need something like this:

```
<root>
    <someValue myAttrib="valueOne"
               anotherAttrib="valueTwo" />
</root>
```

I made some tests using XDocument class, but it does not worked.

Thanks in advance.

What I have tested so far (the commented lines doesn't work):

```
var document = XDocument.Parse("<root></root>");

var xml = new XElement("someValue",
    new XAttribute("myAttrib", "valueOne"),
    //new XAttribute("&#xA", ""),
    //new XAttribute("\r\n", ""),
    new XAttribute("anotherAttrib", "valueTwo")
    );
```

Comment: show us your attempt which doesn't work...

Comment: Please show us your code...

Comment: try to define XmlWriterSettings and set NewLineOnAttributes to true

Comment: Sargis, perhaps it would works, but I just want to set linebreak in the "someValue" tag. Thanks for contribute